# JSF selectBooleanCheckbox uncheck after click

Tags: jsf, checkbox

I am using `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` in my page, the value of them is getting from the backing bean. In this way:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{billing.selected}">
    <f:ajax render="billingEventsGroup" event="valueChange" execute="@this" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I checked it and after that go next or back pages (I have PrimeFaces wizard to do that). When I come back to the page, the checkBox is unchecked.

Some clue about that behaviour?

Comment: It looks that you're using `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped` for this wizard. A possible solution would be to change the bean to `@SessionScoped` but that means you have to delete it later manually in case the user want to use this wizard option again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendonza if the "next" and "previous" buttons are ajax-based, the Update Model phase is not called, so the value is not set in the backing bean. Is that right? If OP set the default checkbox's value to true and unselect it, going back/forth will cause the checkbox to be checked again.

Comment: @kauedg the update model phase will be called even on ajax requests because they're requests after all.

Comment: Symptoms indicate that `#{billing}` is reinstantiated/reconstructed in the meanwhile. Is this true? Or are you absolutely positive that you're dealing with the same instance throughout the process? Putting a debug breakpoint on bean's constructor should give clues.

Comment: The bean is in Session scope. I am sure the billing is the same instance throughout the process.  I made a test displaying the billing value, despite being true the checkbox is unchecked.